# How would you represent a custom timezone? a custom time range for a day?

Tags: r

Suppose you wanted to create a date/time convention in R that was from 6PM NY time to 5PM NY time [following day] (typical trading day in NY). I suppose that would make 6PM NY time correspond to 00:00 in that timezone and 5PM NY time (following day) correspond to 23:00. (suppose we call this a custom timezone)

Suppose I had timestamps in Japan time, Australia and Moscow times that I wanted to convert them to fall on day/times within this custom timezone. Looking for a manageable way to convert every time stamp to this custom date/time convention and make all live in this timezone (sort-of). What is the most seamless way to do it?

> NOTE: Would prefer a base-R solution but other solutions would be
>   interesting

Comment: Have you looked at the available `GMT/Etc` time zones? There may be one available that matches your needs. Also look at the `lubridate` package which has helper functions for time zones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do what you want without any packages.

First, you take the timestamp. If it is already in a POSIXct format, it will have the time zone already encoded in it. If it is in a character format, that will be handled too by converting it to a POSIXct object.

Next, you find out what the time difference was between New York and the place where the time stamp came from. You can do this by converting the time stamp to a string, then back to a POSIXct object with tz set to "America/New_York". Subtracting the original time stamp from this gives you the time difference between New York and the other location.

Now all you need to do is add this time to the "phony" NY time and subtract 18 hours.

To make your head spin a little less, we'll label the resulting times as "UTC" for "Universal Trading Clock"

```
universal_trading_clock <- function(timestamp, tz = "America/New_York")
{
  if(is.character(timestamp)) timestamp <- as.POSIXct(timestamp, tz = tz)
  NY_time       <- as.POSIXct(substr(timestamp, 1, 19), tz = "America/New_York")
  time_diff     <- NY_time - timestamp
  trading_time  <- NY_time + time_diff - 64800
  as.POSIXct(substr(trading_time, 1, 19), tz = "UTC")
}
```

So let's see what 6:05 pm in NYC is today according to the Universal Trading Clock:

```
universal_trading_clock("2020-02-28 18:05:00")
#> [1] "2020-02-28 00:05:00 UTC"
```

And what was the "UTC" time for Japan at 9am local time?

```
universal_trading_clock("2020-02-28 09:00:00", "Japan")
#> [1] "2020-02-27 15:00:00 UTC"
```

Remember, to get this to work, you need to know the names of the timezones. The following should work for you:

- "America/New_York"
- "Japan"
- "Europe/Moscow"
- "Australia/Canberra"

Comment: I think 'EST' is an invalid timezone. I think it should probably be 'America/New_York' but I like your idea!

Comment: @Denis it works on my PC as you can see from the above example

Comment: 'EST' refers to a time-zone in Canada that does not observe daylight savings time, NOT US Eastern Standard Time. It's one of those quirky things in R that I deal with all the time. No idea why someone designed it this way... :-)

Comment: @Denis in that case I'll update it to America/New_York in my example